# Remove parenthesis and numbers from names?

Tags: python

There is a list containing the names of several countries but some have numbers and/or parenthesis in their name. I want to get a clean list with only the country names without the parenthesis or number part. Is there a good pythonic way to do it quickly?

**Example:**

**Input:**

```
country = ['India12','Bolivia (SA)', 'Australia17 (A)']
```

**Output:**

```
country = ['India','Bolivia', 'Australia']
```

**Note:** I am currently using a C like code in Python where I iterate over the whole string and remove the string part from the position where I first encounter a number or a parenthesis. I want a cleaner and shorter code.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: You  may use regex

Comment: Don't edit to say you have code. Actually show it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use regular-expression for the same. Here is an approach to do the same

```
import re
pattern = '[a-zA-Z]+'
country = ['India12','Bolivia (SA)', 'Australia17 (A)']
country_names = map(lambda x:re.search(pattern,x).group(),country)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex :

```
import re
List = [re.findall("([a-zA-Z]+)[ \d]*[(]*.*[)]*.*", i)[0] for i in country]
```

Output :

```
>>> List
['India', 'Bolivia', 'Australia']
```